# JavaScript select dropdown not working in mobile

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, html-select

I am using this select dropdown to change contents of a table on mobile.

It works on desktop but when I try it on mobile devices it doesn't change the content.

I've racked my brain for a good couple of days.

HTML:

```
<select class="compare-dropdown"> 
  <option selected="selected">1 Year account</option> 
  <option>2 Year account</option> 
  <option>3 Year account</option> 
  <option>5 Year account</option> 
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
// DIRTY Responsive pricing table JS

$( "select" ).on( "change", "option", function() {
  var pos = $(this).index()+2;
  $parent = $(this).closest('article');
  $parent.find("tr").find('td:not(:eq(0))').hide();
  $parent.find('td:nth-child('+pos+')').css('display','block');
  $parent.find("tr").find('th:not(:eq(0))').hide();
});

// Initialize the media query
  var mediaQuery = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 640px)');

  // Add a listen event
  mediaQuery.addListener(doSomething);

  // Function to do something with the media query
  function doSomething(mediaQuery) {    
    if (mediaQuery.matches) {
      $('.sep').attr('colspan',5);
    } else {
      $('.sep').attr('colspan',2);
    }
  }

  // On load
  doSomething(mediaQuery);
```

If you have any help that would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Does it work in the mobile device emulator in your browser DevTools?

Comment: I am not sure if the change event is guaranteed to originate from the "option" node. It might originate from the "select" node in some browsers. Try removing the second parameter of your .on() call

Comment: Update: it's not working in browser now as I changed the code, it used to be

    $( "select" ).on( "click", "option", function() {

But I changed it and it's not working anywhere now

Comment: Sorry Jannes, what do mean?

Answer (score 0):

The second argument must be a callback function:

```
$( "select" ).on( "change", function() {
  var pos = $(this).index()+2;
  $parent = $(this).closest('article');
  $parent.find("tr").find('td:not(:eq(0))').hide();
  $parent.find('td:nth-child('+pos+')').css('display','block');
  $parent.find("tr").find('th:not(:eq(0))').hide();
});
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on this please?

Comment: Here is the docs https://api.jquery.com/change/#change. You should use this pattern `.on( "change", handler )` to handle your change event. handler is your function in which you specify all actions after event fired.

Comment: Hey Vadi, unfortunately this isn't working, it doesnt seem to be targeting the content

Comment: It's not clear from your code what is `.sep`? But all actions in the handler react to change event both on pc (chrom) and chrome mobile device emulator.

Comment: '.sep' isn't relevant here, I need to be able to change the 'options' under the 'select'

Comment: ok, but your html contains only select part, not table part that must be changed as a result. I suggest (as actions in the handler react to change event), there might be something wrong on the part related content.